# SQL Server 2008 Freeze a view and refresh it periodically

Tags: sql-server, view

in a Symfony/Doctrine project I use a database that I am not allowed to modify. I must be compatible with SQL Server 2008. I created a view from a table of this DB (the view is in my DB which is in SQL Server 2008), a very basic view. But the table being not indexed, without primary key... Queries on this view can take between 200ms and 8000ms! I wanted to have if it was possible to "freeze" this view and update it every 1-5 minutes. In the context of use ask I do not need to have refreshment faster.

Comment: That's not how a `VIEW` work. To quote the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017) *"A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query. Like a table, a view consists of a set of named columns and rows of data. Unless indexed, a view does not exist as a stored set of data values in a database. **The rows and columns of data come from tables referenced in the query defining the view and are produced dynamically when the view is referenced**. "*. If you want static data, you'll need to create a table to store it in.

Comment: Why not index the table(s)/view if you know that that is the issue?

Comment: @Larnu I can only do "select" on the database to which I can make no changes. I'll create a table and update it, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can't change it, who can? Maybe speak to them to fix their design if the performance is that bad.

Comment: Our company is a reseller of an ERP solution for industries. We are developing modules compatible with this 20 year old ERP. The company that developed the ERP does software updates and does not keep us informed of future developments. We just know that it tries to be as backward compatible as possible with the old version. She's starting to make her relational database with primary and foreign keys... I'll have to wait for her to do it for my table but by then I want to find a solution for performance problems related to that.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator